# zsh: Force single tab completion

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-completion

I recently switched from bash to zsh. How can I achieve the following tab completion behavior:

Enter the first letters, then press `TAB`. Complete the entry until the first ambiguous letter and immediately show the options / alternatives.

Currently, it behaves like this:

```
# ls .m*
  .mysql_history  .matlab  .matplotlib  .mono  .mozilla
# cd .m<TAB>
  .matlab/  .matplotlib/  .mono/  .mozilla/
# cd .mo<TAB>
  .mono/  .mozilla/
# cd .ma<TAB><TAB> (here two tabs are necessary: the first one completes to .mat, 
                    the second one show .matlab and .matplotlib)
```

I'd like to get rid of the second tab in the last case. Is this possible with zshs completion system?

Here is my current `.zshrc`:

```
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=1000

# Options
setopt autocd

# Aliases
alias ls='ls --color -h --group-directories-first'
alias ll='ls -laF --color -h --group-directories-first'
alias la='ls -A --color -h --group-directories-first'


alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'

# Prompt
PS1="[%n@%m]%F{112}[%~]%f# "

# Enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
fi

# Set vim mode
bindkey -v

# Key bindings
# Vi insert mode
bindkey -M viins 'jj' vi-cmd-mode
bindkey -M vicmd '^i' vi-down-line-or-history
bindkey -M vicmd '^k' vi-up-line-or-history

# Vi command mode
bindkey -M vicmd 'l' vi-forward-char
bindkey -M vicmd '^l' vi-forward-word
bindkey -M vicmd 'j' vi-backward-char
bindkey -M vicmd '^j' vi-backward-word
bindkey -M vicmd 'h' vi-insert
bindkey -M vicmd 'i' vi-down-line-or-history
bindkey -M vicmd 'k' vi-up-line-or-history

# Environment variables
export TERM=xterm-256color

# Completion
zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/jeschma/.zshrc'

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, i've found out that the zsh option `listambiguous` was set by default. I just inserted `unsetopt listambiguous` into my zshrc and my problem was solved. Now the possible completions are show with a single `TAB` press every time.